# Running SSL and non-SSL on same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 123.0.1.2:80>
ServerName website.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/website.com"
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 123.0.1.2:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/website.com"
ServerName website.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/ssl/testing/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/testing/server.key
<Directory "/var/www/website.com">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
SSLVerifyClient none
</VirtualHost>
```

However this gives me an SSL protocol error, which I don't get if I remove the first VirtualHost.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `NameVirtualHost`.

Try to add the following

```
NameVirtualHost 123.0.1.2:80
NameVirtualHost 123.0.1.2:443
```

More information:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: That gives me [warn] NameVirtualHost 123.0.1.2:443 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: Check here and make sure your configuration is proper. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations/

Comment: Umm, yeah, I don't see any problems with mine. New version is here: http://pastebin.com/TZXfQYTd

Comment: Just to make sure, you have Listen-directives for both ports?

Comment: Yes, Listen *:443 Listen *:80

Comment: Out of the blue.. Try to change `NameVirtualHost` and `VirtualHost` to match your listen directives.

Comment: Okay, I've actually changed it around and added the NameVirtualHost to the ports.conf file. It doesn't produce any errors now, but, I get an endless redirect even when I remove the Rewrite rule.

Comment: Appears it was deny from all in .htaccess file.

Comment: Great that you found it :)